# C# yammer api export csv file

Tags: c#, yammer

I 'm looking for a code which exports Yammer data in zip file like I need only message.csv, users.csv, groups.csv, could you please help ?
I 'm getting 20 messages initially instead of all public messages and I want to get data based on date how to pass query for the same ?

Code I have used

```
 wr = WebRequest.CreateHttp(Url);
                wr.Method = "GET";

                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
                    wr.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authHeader);

                wResp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();

                Stream dataStream = wResp.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                results = reader.ReadToEnd();

                reader.Close();
```

Comment: Are you wanting to write some code that connects to the Yammer api and downloads the above data a zip it up?

Comment: Yes @KevinSmith

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HttpClient` to call the given endpoints that are described at https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ then you can then save these to disk using `File.Write` Then you can create Zip file using the `ZipFile` object - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

There's a lot to all this, It might be worth having a stab at something and when you get stuck create a question related to a specific problem area.

Comment: Kevin, I tried the application using api however for messages I get only 20 message, I have edited my question please check